# How to check whether particular user_id is present in user_id field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What want to write a query to check if `user_id=10` is exists in mongodb. If `user_id=10` already exists, then edit its other fields. If it does not exist, then insert user_id=10 along with other fields.
I am using meteor js.

Below is the code:

```
Meteor.methods({
'dbs.update'(user_id,name,add)
{
if (Dbs.find){user_id:user_id}))
{         
if(typeof name !=="undefined" && name)
{
Dbs.update({user_id:user_id},{$set: {name: name}});
}
if(typeof add !=="undefined" && add)
{
 Dbs.update({user_id:user_id},{$set: {add:add}});
}
}
else
{
Dbs.insert({user_id:user_idname:name,add:add});
}
}
```

With this code i am  able to update existing records.but not able to insert new records if not existing.
`db.collection.find({ "user_id" : { $exists : true}})`:checks for  field `user_id` is present or not.So is there any query to check particular id/value exists in field `user_id` ?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your existing mongo document?

Comment: {"_id" : "***",
 "user_id" : "",
 "name" : "",
 "add" : "" }

Comment: What should i replace with this:" if (Dbs.find){user_id:user_id}))" if condition to check  the user_id that i am passing is present or not.and if not present then it should go to else part:"Dbs.insert({user_id:user_idname:name,add:add});"other code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your latest comment, the below should work.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'dbs.update' (user_id, name, add) {

        // find at least one doc which contains the user_id passed.
        var getUserDocument = Dbs.findOne({
            user_id: user_id
        });



        if (getUserDocument) { // if there exists a document with the given user_id

            // do your update stuff here

        } else { // if no doc has been found with user_id (which means that getUserDocument will be undefined)

            //do your insert.
            Dbs.insert({
                user_id: user_id,
                name: name,
                add: add
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, what exactly is not working? Is it always skipping to the else part?

Comment: When i pass new id it is not inserting it in database.I just used "alert" to check what getUserDocument stores.it shows undefined.

Comment: This is server side code. So you have to ```console.log``` to check if it's inserted. Or check mongo directly. Make sure you have proper publication / subscription so that the same doc is available on the  client . If not you'll always get an ```undefined``` on the client side. I'm hoping all this has been taken care.

Comment: Its working @blueren.I guess i made some typing mistake so it was not inserting.Thank you so much.finally its working.